# No name matching in AKHQ

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, akhq

Getting `No name matching` error while connecting to kafka from AKHQ

```
2022-04-11 09:15:35,806 WARN  inclient-2 c.a.i.AdminMetadataManager [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-2] Metadata update failed due to authentication error
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SslAuthenticationException: SSL handshake failed
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No name matching ppe.kafka.tnt.dev.euw.azure.tesco.org found
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.runDelegatedTasks(SslTransportLayer.java:430)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshakeUnwrap(SslTransportLayer.java:514)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.doHandshake(SslTransportLayer.java:368)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.handshake(SslTransportLayer.java:291)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:178)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
      at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:551)
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.processRequests(KafkaAdminClient.java:1389)
      at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient$AdminClientRunnable.run(KafkaAdminClient.java:1320)
      at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching test.server.host.name found
      at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
      ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the Kafka server's certificate does not match the hostname. We could set `ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm` to an empty string to disable hostname verification.

> The endpoint identification algorithm used by clients to validate
> server host name. The default value is https. Clients including client
> connections created by the broker for inter-broker communication
> verify that the broker host name matches the host name in the broker’s
> certificate. Disable server host name verification by setting
> ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm to an empty string

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_ssl.html#optional-settings